# Contents of Qlistwidget based on selection of an item in another qlistwidget

Tags: qt4

I'm using QT Creator to develop an application. I have two QTListWidgets which are aligned side by side.

I've populated the first qtlistwidget with some items using the 'Edit List Widget' dialogue box.

Now based on which item is selected in the first qtkistwidget  , I would like to have options in the second qtlistwidget. These options in the second qtkistwidget should change with a change of selection in the first one .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [`QStringListModel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtreewidget.html) and using [`QTreeView`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtreeview.html)s for your views.  Keep a collection of the models to use in the second view, and set the model appropriately when the first view's selection changes.

Comment: thanks a lot.. I'll give it a shot and get back.. thanks again